# how to implement smart indent in python as done in Matlab

Tags: python, indentation

Is there anyone who know some way to automate the correct indentation in coding in Python?
For example, when I write codes as follows:

```
if condition1:
print a
else:
print b
```

Then the codes should be formatted as follows:

```
if condition1:
    print a
else:
    print b*
```

I use Spyder for python programming. Thanks!

Comment: Use a IDE or Text Editor like Sublime. That will make your life easier

Comment: I've edited your formatting to put the code in code blocks. Please double check this is the formatting you intended

Comment: That is not a Python issue. It depends only in the text editor or IDE you are using. There is no way that Python can know that a non indented line belongs to the previous function or class, as it unindent is the mechanism it has for knowing that the function code has ended.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting [ATOM](https://atom.io/) it is a great text editor for python. By the way have you tried saving your source file as something.py before you gone ahead and started type in your code? it might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to python and doing scientific computing.  I really like the  [PyCharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).  I am using the free community version, and it works great for me.

In any case, I believe this is a function of the IDE.